# Layout Update XML in magento2 pages in backend

Tags: magento2, cms-pages

I want to add some other blogs in pages using `2 columns with right bar` in pages.
For example, I have added code like remove wishlist and I have added my custom block in that Layout Handle in the backend. But it's not working. Please tell me how to fix this.

Layout handle in pages screnshot:
https://prnt.sc/i4reka

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.sidebar" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="wishlist_sidebar" remove="true"/>
        <referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional">
            <block class="Custom\Blog\Block\Sidebar" name="blog.sidebar" template="Custom_Blog::sidebar.phtml" after="-"/>
        </referenceContainer>      
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Magento 2 only support updates of  `referenceContainer, container, update, move`  layout tags from admin**.

So, from **Layout Update XML section**, cannot remove a block
using

```
<referenceBlock name="{Blockname}" remove="true"/>
```

### So, how to remove a block from Layout Update XML

An Idea ,we do trick, by which we you remove  a block from layout

**1. First create [new container](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html) for layout**

> `<container name="removeusedlayout.page" as="removeunsedlayout"
>   label="Remove used use container" htmlTag="div"
>   htmlClass="removeunsedlayout-container" />`

2.Move all blocks (**`which you want remove from layout`**) to this container to this ***referenceContainer***  `removeusedlayout.page`

> ```
> <move element="wishlist_sidebar" destination="removeusedlayout.page"/>
> ```

3. Then **remove container** `removeusedlayout.page` from layout using below code:

> ```
> <referenceContainer name="removeusedlayout.pager" remove="true"/>
> ```

[image]

**Output**
[image]

Comment: There is a typo error (pager instead of page) in your last referenceContainer, isn't there ?